# Finding a function by solving equation of its derivative

Tags: integration, derivatives

Could anyone find y from below equation?

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = a y(x) +  v(x)$$
I'm not sure if the answer I found is correct or not: $\ln(a y + v(x)) = x$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, $v$ is not a constant, so you can't integrate like that. Instead, look for an integrating factor to write the terms involving $y$ as one derivative: something like $\frac{1}{\mu} d(\mu y)/dx$. Differentiating this using the product rule shows it is equal to $dy/dx-ay$ when $\frac{d\mu/dx}{\mu} = -a$, or $\log{\mu}=-ax$, $\mu = e^{-ax}$ (there's no need for a multiplicative constant of integration since it will cancel out). Then
$$ e^{ax}\frac{d}{dx}(e^{-ax}y(x)) = v(x), $$
or
$$ \frac{d}{dx}(e^{-ax}y(x)) = e^{-ax}v(x). $$
We can integrate this to find
$$ e^{-ax} y(x) = A + \int^x e^{-at} v(t) \, dt, $$
or
$$ y(x) = Ae^{ax} + e^{ax}\int^x e^{-at} v(t) \, dt. $$
This is the best you can do without the specific form of the function $v$.

Comment: v(x) = c e^(-b x)

Comment: v(x) = c e^(-b x)